# Service Worker: pitfalls of self.skipWaiting() and self.clients.claim()

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

To immediately activate a service worker after it's installed, I use `self.skipWaiting()` in the install listener. To immediately take control of a page (without the need for a page navigation, e.g. page load), I use `self.clients.claim()`. I understand that doing such things means:

- Page could first load without it being under the control of a Service Worker, but then be taken over by a Service Worker during its lifespan.
- A page could start under the control of version 1 of Service Worker but then be taken over by version 2 during its lifespan.

There are all kinds of warnings online about doing such things, but I don't see the pitfalls. Perhaps one potential problem is if the controlled page does some initial handshake or setup with a Service Worker when it first loads. That obviously will be missed when the new Service Worker activates in the background, but even then, the Service Worker could message its controlling pages to notify them of the change.

It seems to me that for most applications under most scenarios would benefit significantly by using both `self.skipWaiting()` and `self.clients.claim()` without any downside. Did I miss something?

Comment: It could lead to incompatible file handling. Imagine you have loaded html v1, then your service worker changes and it loads ressources from v2 which match not in your v1 html.

Comment: @StefChäser Why would that be a problem? If it is a problem, wouldn't it be easy to work around it?

Comment: read this one : https://redfin.engineering/how-to-fix-the-refresh-button-when-using-service-workers-a8e27af6df68 with parent-thread ... https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1120

Comment: See also: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle

Comment: @RobertRowntree the article from Redfin is fantastic! There are serious implications of `self.skipWaiting()` and he provides great workarounds. He doesn't refer to `self.clients.claim()`, but from what I gather, there's less risk in using that (i.e. page loads without service worker control, but gets taken over shortly thereafter) as there are no old caches to contend with.

Answer (score 2):

The pitfalls of `self.skipWaiting()` is described really well here (thanks @RobertRowntree for the link):

https://redfin.engineering/how-to-fix-the-refresh-button-when-using-service-workers-a8e27af6df68

As for `self.clients.claim()`, I still haven't seen a compelling argument against it, but when I do, I'll update my answer.